# Give me a hint on FormClosing event 

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MainForm. I can close it by using a close button (upper right corner) or by clicking a menuitem miExit.

My problem is when I clicked miExit and answered "OK", it shows messageBox **TWICE**. How can I fix it ? (I understand why it shows twice but how can I avoid it ?)

Both formclosing and miExit clicks must provide messagebox with "Exit ?" prompt.

```
partial class MainForm : Form
{
    void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Exit ?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,         MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            SaveSettings();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    void miExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Exit ?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,             MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
    SaveSettings();

            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    void SaveSettings()
    {
    // save user settings to file ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `miExit_Click` handlier to just call [`Application.Exit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx)

`Application.Exit()` automatically calls the `FormClosing` event on all open forms.  And yes, these forms can cancel the Exit by setting their `FormClosingEventArgs`'s `Cancel` property to `true`.

P.S. If you don't believe me, I linked to the documentation for `Application.Exit()`, the `FormClosing` bit is the first bullet point under Remarks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `miExit_Click` event handler to do nothing but call `Close` and then let the `FormClosing` handler handle it either way it's being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Apply **[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)** here. You have redundant code for Form Close.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 0):

Replace the contents of miExit_Click with 'this.Close();' which will in turn call MainForm_FormClosing so you don't need that code twice. Job done